# Change color of user control

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

Is possible to change color of user control directly in my view ?

```
<local:MyControl
  // properties
/>
```

I've tried use "Foreground" property, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

If you have children controls inside the user control (eg. textboxes) in your control, then you can bind their foreground property to the control's foreground.
Example:

```
<local:MyControl>
  <TextBox Foreground="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyControl}}}"/>
  <TextBlock Foreground="the same binding"/>
  ...
</local:MyControl>
```

If the user control doesn't implements any base type class (eg. `FrameworkElement` or `UserControl`), then you have to create the `Foreground` property, and if you want to use WPF binding too, also the decency property for it.
Code in MyControl.xaml.cs:

```cs
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ForegroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Foreground", typeof(Brush), typeof(MyControl));
    public Brush Foreground {
      get { return (Brush)GetValue(ForegroundProperty); }
      set { SetValue(ForegroundProperty, value); }
    }
```

In the second case you should also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for updating the WPF control properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple Change any property of your `UserControl`. For example:

```
<local:MyControl Foreground="Red" Background="#FF008080"/>
```

To make this work it is necassary to process these properties (or further custom properties) in the control. `Background` and `Foreground` is applied to the control it self. But you can also bind other control properties to These color/brush properties.

```
<Button Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=myBindingTarget}" />
<!-- or some other binding -->
<Button Background="{Binding }"/>
```